# Example of non distributive module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, lattice-orders

I'm looking for a module that has three submodules $P,Q,R$  such that $P\cap (Q+R) \neq P\cap Q +P\cap R $ I'm struggling to find this example because I'm not that familiarized in module theory
Can You help me?
Thanks

Comment: Just a note that in the setting of ideals: For $I,J,K$ ideals of $R$ commutative with $1$, we have $I(J+K) = IJ+IK$ and $(I+J)K=IK+JK$. So to get a counterexample, we want some example where $IJ\neq I\cap J$.

Answer (score 6):

Take a field $k$, and the vector space $k^2$. Let $P=\{(x,x):x\in k\}$, $Q=\{(x,0):x\in k\}$, and $R=\{(0,y):y\in k\}$. Then $Q+R=k^2$, so $P\cap(Q+R)=P$, but $P\cap Q=0=P\cap R$.

Answer (score 3):

The smallest example is to take the Klein $4$-group viewed as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. Then take $P$, $Q$, and $R$ to be the nontrivial proper subgroups, any two of which generate the whole group, but have trivial intersection.

Note that in general you can consider abelian groups to be $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, so you can use them to provide examples/counterexamples for general statements about modules, if you are more familiar with them and modules in general.